# How to structurally pattern match builtin type slice in python?

Tags: python, structural-pattern-matching

How to structurally pattern match builtin type slice in python?

Somewhy the following code does not work:

```py
def __getitem__(self, index):
    match index:
        case int(i):
           ...
        case slice(start, stop, step):
           ...
        case _:
           ...
```

and I completely do not understand why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
class Example:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        match index:
            case int(i):
                print('int', i)
            case slice(start=start, stop=stop, step=step):
                print('slice', start, stop, step)
            case _:
                print('default')

e = Example()
e[1]
e[1:2]
```

Prints:

```
int 1
slice 1 2 None
```

Comment: Don't just post code, explain what was wrong and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

`slice` does not have a `__match_args__` attribute, so it does not support positional patterns. It only supports keyword patterns for its three data descriptors `start`, `stop` and `step`.

```
match index:
    case int(i):
        print(f"Integer {i}")
    case slice(start=t1, stop=t2, step=t3):
        print(f"Start {t1} stop {t2} step {t3}")
    case _:
        print("Other")
```

(While PEP 634 seems to suggest that an `AttributeError` will be raised if you attempt to use positional patterns, it seems a `TypeError` is raised instead.)